# Cut lines when they cross another line via symbology in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, line, intersection

I am currently preparing roads from OSM data. For this I want to display the roads with 2 lines at the roadside. I have set this without any problems via the symbol layer properties (see image). However, it is now the case that the lines overlap and I would like to display the lines in such a way that these are cut off when crossing another line.

[image]
The black lines correspond to my visualization and the orange lines represent the roads as simple lines.

I have already tried to set the symbolization accordingly via the function Cut line, but since the roads do not always consist of only one segment, this leads to an incorrect dipiction.

[image]

Comment: And taking the lines, make a buffer as polygon, merge all the polygons? It would not be a solution?

Comment: The symbology would work, but then all roads would have the same width - what is not given. Also all the informations like streetname, type of road etc. would be lost.